# cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails mysql

Tags: mysql, constraints

Hi I'm pretty new to mysql and have tried some of the other suggested fixes for this problem but had no luck! I'm trying to create a foreign key between the tables application and customer but when i run my program I get the error "`cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails mysql`". My program is a data capture form and is meant to insert the information into the database.

Table Schemas:

**application table:**

```
applicationid mediumint(9)
covertype varchar(100)
customeremail varchar(100)
```

**customertable:**

```
customeremail varchar(100)
customerfname varchar(100)
applicationid mediumint(9)
```

I tried to set up a foreign key a few different ways e.g.
alter table application add foreign key(customeremail) references customer(customeremail)
alter table customer add foreign key (applicationid) references application(applicationid)

But this didn't work i'd appreciate any advice on how to solve the issue

Comment: Add query that gives you along with error share with us what till now you tried?

Comment: first of all you should read about db normalization : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Perhaps you should take some time to edit your question to show more context information and/or coe if relevant. Anyway, while waiting for answers you may I suggest you spend some time reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You should try that syntax:

```
alter table application 
         add foreign key(customeremail) 
         references application(applicationid)
```

That means, a value in column `customeremail` from table `application` *is only allowed if* there is the same value in the column `applicationid` of (at least) one row of the table `application`.

Depending your background, you could think to that as a "pointer" -- but is relational algebra relations are bidirectional.

In addition, for this to work, you *must* have an index on the *target*. Here on `application`.`applicationid`. If this in *not* the case, you should write:

```
alter table application add index (applicationid)
```

My *guess* is this shouldn't be necessary since there is great chances that `applicationid` is your `PRIMARY KEY`.

---

BTW, as *Stephan* suggested it in comment, and since you are "pretty new to DB" you should definitively take a look at proper documentation about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

Comment: Hi Sylvain i tried that and got the following error: 1005 Can't create table '40029562.#sql-9d8_ac' //40029562 is my schema name

Comment: @Claire This is a strange error message. Could you try to create your tables in http://sqlfiddle.com? That would be easier for us to test-and-try.